# Python xlsxwriter static date into dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm format

Tags: python, datetime, xlsxwriter

[image: Please check this]

I tried using datetime_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM' but this didn't change it. How else can I get the date to format like this?

Comment: Please post your code as text.

Comment: I need to get date and time in excel sheet as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM
and i tried
format7 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss AM/PM', 'align': 'left'})
worksheet.write_datetime('C3:D3',  conflict_report.affected_at.date(),format7)

But error message popuped

Comment: What was the error?  Please add it to the question.

Comment: No error. I can't get the date format as i wanted to . That's the problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does the `.date()` method return a Datetime instance or a string in date format?

Comment: @jmcnamara it returns date as dd-mm-yy and 12:00:00 AM , the time is not changing . it is fixed as 12:00 am and date format also not changing the format to dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: If the format isn't applying then the most common reason is that the data it is being applied to is a string and not a number/date. That is why I asked if that function returns a string or date.